# How to run `npm install && bower install` before `sbt compile` for Heroku Deployment?

Tags: node.js, scala, heroku

I am working on a Playframework project which has front-end codes in sub-directory `./ui` and managed by Grunt using https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman

Currently I used https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi and set

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

in the .buildpacks file.

And set

```
{
  "name": "scala-grunt",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~0.10.21"
  }

}
```

in the `package.json` file of root directory.

However, when I pushed the code base to heroku it will throw an exception `Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.` I think that is because sbt doesn't to run `npm install && bower install` in the `./ui` directory.

Does anyone have ideas about how to run a command `npm install && bower install` before `sbt compile` in heroku?

Comment: Are you aware of [`sbt-heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku) plugin? With this plugin you can stage your play app locally and deploy it to Heroku. It only remains to stage the app with necessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts.  There are a couple keywords you can use to run bower and grunt at different times.  Check out the `preinstall` and `postinstall` keyword.

For an example, here is my script section from my package.json file that I use a lot.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node lib/app.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install --allow-root",
    "test": "grunt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This command solved for me:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```